# Binding a dictionary to WPF control with ability for user to edit the values

Tags: c#, wpf-controls

I'm writing an application in WPF C#

I have a dictionary<string, int>, the dictionary->keys are added in code, with default values for dictionary->value. and I want to give the user to edit for each key in dictionary his value.

In other words I want to bind a dictionary to a control, the key should be displayed on screen, and the value should be the input from user.

what's the best way to do it ?

I thought of creating a **combobox**, that each line has a **label** for the dictionary.**key** and a **textBox** to enter the **value**.
can I do that? if yes how?

I don't want to create a whole data grid, (not that data grid I know how to). I want something small and neaty, like a combobox.

I didn't try yet anything I'm still looking around how to do it.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Create a Combo Box populate with "label" when selected it gives the "key" As for entering data I need further information SIDE NOTE I quit using key value pairs when I learned to use SQLite DB